# Call digamma()-function in NLOPT-optimization procedure in C++

Tags: c++, boost, nlopt

I use the [NLOPT](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_C-plus-plus_Reference) library on Visual Studio 2015 for an optimization problem which involves a multi-parameter objective function & a gradient-vector. The shortened code looks like this:

```
#include "C:\C++\Boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\math\special_functions\digamma.hpp"   
double my_objective_function(unsigned length, const double *x, double *grad, void* dat) {

    // pointer on data
    double *dat_Ptr = static_cast<double*>(dat);

    // objective function (shortened)
    double obj = x[0]*std::tgamma(1 + 1/x[0]) + ...

    // gradient-vector (shortened)
    double grad[4];
    grad[0] = -1.0*boost::math::digamma(1.0 + 1.0/x[0]) + ...

    /*
        further code 
    */
```

Using the `NLOPT_LD_LBFGS` & calling `boost::math::digamma()`-function yields the following error: [image: Error]

This error does not come up if I change `boost::math::digamma(1.0 + 1.0/x[0])` to `boost::math::digamma(1.0 + 1.0/5.4)` etc. So when I take the parameter x[0] 
out it works fine. The same error occurs when I use another `boost::math`-function but not if I use its `std::`-counterpart.

**Q: Why can't I apply `boost::math`-functions to parameters which are optimized? Is there another way to include the `digamma()`-function (except for using  Taylor approximation of it)?**

Thanks for any help. I can give further details but the code is extensive and I guess I already filtered out the problem at hand. 
**EDIT**: The `main()` which calls the function above.

```
#include "C:\C++\Boost\boost_1_55_0\boost\math\special_functions\digamma.hpp"   
#include <vector>
#include "nlopt.hpp"
#include "myCSV.h"      // CSV-Parser to read-in data for optimization

int main(){

    // DATA IMPORT
    ifstream file("C:/data.txt");
    CSVRow row;
    int j = 0;
    double dat[50000];

    while (file >> row)
        dat[j] = stod(row[1]);

    // OPTIMIZATION

    nlopt_opt opt_object;
    opt_object = nlopt_create(NLOPT_LD_LBFGS, (4));

    double lb[4] = { 0.0, 0.0 , 0.0, 0.0};
    nlopt_set_lower_bounds(opt_object, lb);

    nlopt_set_max_objective(opt_object, my_objective_function, dat);        // Call of the function defined in my 1st post
    nlopt_set_xtol_rel(opt_object, 1e-8);

    double x[4] = { 1,0.5,0.5,0.5 };                                                            
    double maxf;
    nlopt_optimize(opt_object, x, &maxf);

    printf("Result: f(%g, %g, %g, %g) = %0.10g\n", x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], maxf);

    nlopt_destroy(opt_object);
}
```

Comment: Without knowing that `number_of_parameters` you should know that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of the C++ language. Some compilers have it as an extension of the language though, but I recommend against using it for portability reasons. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: As for your problem, have you checked that `x` is pointing somewhere valid? How do you call your function? What do you pass your functions? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll keep the vector declaration in mind for the future. I left it in my example. The x-pointer is valid. Again, the problem only arises when a boost-function is applied to an argument involving x[0] etc.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but is the input file containing *exactly* 50000 values? If it contains more then you will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*. If it contains fewer, then parts of the array `dat` will be uninitialized with values being *indeterminate* and again have undefined behaviors when you use those values.

Comment: Yes, exactly 50,000. Furthermore there is an integer control variable which stops the parser when exactly 50000 is reached (I left it out to make the example as minimal as possible).